# Multiple Azure WebRoles Using SSL - How do I setup the solution?

Tags: azure, azure-web-roles

I have a solution that will end up looking like this:

http://www.test.com - Public marketing website (port 80)

https://www.test.com - MVC Web application for authenticated users (port 443)

https://api.test.com - WebAPI layer that all clients will use (port 443 hopefully)

Initially the application will be an MVC website but we also plan on developing native clients for Windows Phone, Windows 8, etc. All clients, including the MVC application website will use the WebAPI service layer for data operations. All clients will take advantage of portable class libraries too.

I registered two SSL certificates. One for www.test.com and one for api.test.com.

When I configure the roles (WebRole.Public, WebRole.Application and WebRole.WebAPI) I am told that port 443 is already assigned to another WebRole (the application WebRole in this case) and I need to use the next available port which is 8443.

My concern is that if I use port 8443 it is not firewall friendly which means future clients (Windows Phone, Win8, etc.) will not work without opening up firewalls. I would really like to use 443 on both the application and the webapi WebRoles.

If I setup multiple Azure projects to allow port 443 to be used on WebRole.WebAPI and WebRole.Application will it be possible to debug locally?

What is the recommended solution configuration? We are using Visual Studio 2013.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to use the same port for two sites on the same service, you need to have just one role and set it up with two sites and set a host header for the second site (in your case I'd recommend api.test.com).  There is full [documentation on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/gg433110.aspx).  So your service definition should look something like this:

```
<WebRole name="Test" vmsize="Small">
    <Sites>
      <Site name="Web">
        <Bindings>
          <Binding name="Endpoint1" endpointName="HttpInput" />
          <Binding name="Endpoint1" endpointName="HttpsInput" />
        </Bindings>
      </Site>
      <Site name="Api" physicalDirectory="[Relative Path to Published API">
        <Bindings>
          <Binding name="ApiEndpoint" endpointName="HttpsInput" hostHeader="api.test.com" />
        </Bindings>
      </Site>
    </Sites>
    <Endpoints>
      <InputEndpoint name="HttpInput" protocol="http" port="80" />
      <InputEndpoint name="HttpsInput" protocol="https" port="443" certificate="SSL" />
    </Endpoints>
```

Comment: Does this allow for proper scaling? I wanted to go with separate web roles so I could scale them independently. We are just starting with design so we could go with a different type of SSL certificate or change the domain (e.g. www.test.com/api). We would like to follow the recommended best practice. I will check out the link you provided.

Comment: If you want to scale them separately the solution is much simpler.  You just need to have your two web roles in two different services (cloud projects in VS).  This is because a HTTP port for a service can only be bound to one role at a time.  This does mean that you can't deploy your whole project with just one publish, you'll have to use two instead.  Of course you could run the API as a sub-site for now and then split it into its own role when you need to scale.  This will save you money in the mean time.

Comment: I seem to be able to debug when one cloud project is started without debugging so this might work for us. As far as our SSL certificates go would you recommend using a wildcard certificate and using it for both the www and api sites? Currently I have two separate certs (one for www and one for api).

Comment: That's a question all by itself and will generate debate.  My network manager would say separate certificates as there can be difficulties with wild card certs being recognized by clients.

Answer (score 0):

You can get wildcard SSL certificate and it will work fine for subdomains. You are trying to register two certificates for same port. It is not a good config.

You can call your webapi service in MVC app and host that at different domain, if you don't want to buy wildcard certificate. To debug apps locally, you can use developer express certificate(you approve yourself) and define which port to connect.

Comment: I actually have two distinct certificates, one for www.test.com and one for api.test.com. I can load both certificates fine and apply them to the different WebRoles. The issue is when specifying the port which is 443. I cannot specify 443 for more than one WebRole. Are you saying that if I go with a wildcard SSL certificate I will be able to configure both WebRoles to use port 443 within one solution????